# How to set concurrency limit per task (or queue) in Celery?

Tags: python, concurrency, celery

My example code is:

- run.py

```py
from celery import Celery, Task

app = Celery(
    "app",
    task_serializer='json',
    accept_content=['json'],
    result_serializer='json',
    timezone='Asia/Tokyo',
    enable_utc=True,
    backend='redis://127.0.0.1:6369/2',
    broker='redis://127.0.0.1:6369/3',
    include=['app.tasks']
)

app.conf.task_routes = {'app.tasks.long_run': {'queue': 'long_running_task'}}


class VerboseTask(Task):

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        print("-------------------------------------------")
        print(
            f"FAILURE({task_id})："
            f"{self.request.task}{kwargs}, Exception={exc}, ErrorInfo={einfo}"
        )
        print("-------------------------------------------")

    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        print("-------------------------------------------")
        print(f"SUCCESS({task_id})：{self.request.task}{kwargs}")
        print("-------------------------------------------")

    def on_retry(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        print("-------------------------------------------")
        print(f"RETRY({task_id})：{self.request.task}{kwargs}")
        print("-------------------------------------------")
```

- app/tasks.py

```py
from run import app, VerboseTask
from time import sleep


class TSK:

    name = 'tsk'

    @app.task(bind=True, base=VerboseTask)
    def short_run(self, **kwargs):
        for i in range(0, 3):
            print(f'{self.request.task} [{self.request.id[0:5]}] → {i*5} ~ {(i+1)*5}')
            sleep(5)
        print('short_run finished')

    @app.task(bind=True, base=VerboseTask)
    def long_run(self, **kwargs):
        for i in range(0, 10):
            print(f'{self.request.task} [{self.request.id[0:5]}] → {i*5} ~ {(i+1)*5}')
            sleep(5)
        print('long_run finished')
```

And I run celery with

```
celery -A run worker -l info --concurrency=4 -Q long_running_task,celery
```

The problem is when I invoke `long_running_task` four times and then usual `celery` task, the `long_running_task` consume all workers and `celery` task need to wait for four long running tasks.

I want to keep at least 2 workers for short running tasks. For example if current tasks are two short running tasks and one long running task, then only one worker is available and only short running task able run. Long running task have to wait while three workers will be free at same time to consume one of it.

In other way just limiting of max concurrency for long running task to `2` will be also a possible solution.

I know that I may run two Celery instances with separated concurrency:

```
celery -A run worker -l info --concurrency=2 -n worker1@%h -Q long_running_task
celery -A run worker -l info --concurrency=2 -n worker2@%h -Q celery
```

But

1. I want to consume `long_running_task` workers for other tasks too if that is idle (that is not so important condition and may be ignored)
2. I use docker container and want to keep only one `ENTRYPOINT` inside it (in other words I don't want to separate workers by running separate commands. I want to execute `celery -A run worker ...` only once)

Is here any way to customize limits and concurrency for workers that meet my conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single worker consume from multiple queues. If you have a high_priority queue and a long_running queue, you can have a dedicated worker for the high_priority queue to insure there is always a worker ready to pick those up, and then have the others consume both high_priority and long_running task.

As far as the entrypoint, just use a shell script for entrypoint, that takes a parameter (the list of queues to consume from) so you only have 1 docker image, but 2 deployments: 1 for high_priority queue and 1 for both queues, and you can scale each separately depending on load.